# C# Linq-to-SQL Trying to recive multiple selects

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, multiple-select

I got this SQL code in a SP: (MS SQL 2008)

```
    DECLARE @type tinyint
    SELECT @type = Type FROM Contents WHERE ContentID = @ContentID    

    SELECT [ParentContentID], [Headline], [ShortDescription], [CategoryID], [Type], [State], [DatePublished], [Name] FROM Contents INNER JOIN Users ON Users.ID = Contents.PublishedBy WHERE ContentID = @ContentID

    IF (@type = 2) -- Content with text
    BEGIN
  SELECT [Preamble], [ContentText], [FaceBook], [Twitter], [PrintPage], [TipAFriend] FROM ContentText WHERE ContentID = @ContentID
    END

    SELECT [ID], [ImagePath], [ImageType] FROM ContentImages WHERE ContentID = @ContentID
    SELECT [ID], [BoxID] FROM ContentBoxes WHERE ContentID = @ContentID
```

I thought that i should be smart so i added a Linq-to-SQL class to my project and dragged the SP to the class. However, i can't seem to access the data from the second, third and forth select statement. I was hoping that the Linq-to-SQL class would produce 4 data tables with the information thus letting me access them like: data[2].Row[0].ImagePath.

Do i have to create my own code to get the code from the SQL-server in order to get this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ to SQL does support multiple results sets from stored procedures. You'll want to look at the documentation for `IMultipleResults`, and you'll need to write some code in the data context partial (rather than just relying on what the designer generates). Some links to start you off:

- [IMultipleResults Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.imultipleresults.aspx)
- [Linq to SQL Stored Procedures with Multiple Results](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bursteg/archive/2007/10/05/linq-to-sql-stored-procedures-with-multiple-results-imultipleresults.aspx)
- Other [`IMultipleResults` questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imultipleresults) here on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

I don't think linq-to-sql supports multiple result sets out of the box.

PLINQO, a suite of CodeSmith templates I'm using for my current project, handles this well:
[PLINQO: Stored Procedures with multiple result sets](http://plinqo.com/Features.ashx#Stored_Procedures_with_multiple_result_sets_1)